# Expresión booleana para ir alternando entre 3 casos

Tags: java, booleano

Tengo una duda acerca del siguiente

Código:

```
if (k == 10 && (i == 1 || i == 4 || i == 7 || i == 10 || i == 13 
        || i == 16 || i == 19 || i == 22 || i == 26 || i == 29 
        || i == 32 || i == 35 || i == 38 || i == 41 || i == 44 
        || i == 47 || i == 50 || i == 53 || i == 56 || i == 59)) {
    k = 10;
} else if (k == 10 && (i == 2 || i == 5 || i == 8 || i == 11 
        || i == 14 || i == 17 || i == 20 || i == 23 || i == 27 
        || i == 30 || i == 33 || i == 36 || i == 39 || i == 42 
        || i == 45 || i == 48 || i == 51 || i == 54 || i == 57
        || i == 60)) {
    k = 13;
} else if (k == 10 && (i == 3 || i == 6 || i == 9 || i == 112
        || i == 15 || i == 18 || i == 21 || i == 24 || i == 28 
        || i == 31 || i == 34 || i == 37 || i == 40 || i == 43 
        || i == 46 || i == 49 || i == 52 || i == 55 || i == 58
        || i == 61)) {
    k = 16;
}
```

Este if está dentro de un par de bucles, uno con iterador `i` y otro con `k`. Lo que quiero es que en cada iteración del bucle `i` se cumpla una de estas tres condiciones. Necesito que cuando `i` sea 1 entre en el primer caso, 2 en el segundo y 3 en el tercero y así sucesivamente. Y querría que esto se pueda hacer con todas las iteraciones del bucle.

Mi duda es si existe alguna forma de hacer esto con una expresión simple, y no teniendo que escribir manualmente cada caso.

*Nota: Hay un error en el primer caso, después del 22 i debería valer 25. Lo que hace que toda la secuencia esté mal.

Comment: ¿Por qué no está el `25`? Fue un error cuando armaste la condición? debería ser 25 al 1ro, 26 al 2do y así corrigiendo para todo el resto???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para alternar entre 3 condiciones, siempre en orden, es tan sencillo como usar **el resto de la división**.

```
int resto = i % 3;
```

- Al dividir 1/3 da resto 1, 2/3 da resto 2, 3/3 da resto 0, 4/3 da resto 1, 5/3 da resto 2, 6/3 da resto 0... y así sucesivamente.
- Para `x % N`, el resultado va de 0 a N-1

Así, simplificamos tantas opciones en 1 único valor que va de 0 a 2. Podés usar un `if` para cada opción (o un `switch`, da igual):

```
if (resto == 1) { // caso para 1, 4, 7, 10 ...etc
    //k siempre es 10 acá
} else if (resto == 2) { // caso para 2, 5, 8, 11 ...etc
    k = 13;
} else { // caso para 3, 6, 9, 12 ...etc (resto == 0)
    k = 16;
}
```

> Aunque si únicamente te interesa sumarle 0, 3 o 6 a `k`, todo se puede simplificar sin ningún `if` como:
>
> ```
>    k += ((i - 1) % 3) * 3;
> ```

Comment: Pensé en algo así, pero viendo los grupos de valores, esa regla no se cumple. Observa que en el primer grupo por ejemplo el incremento de `3` se rompe a partir del número `22`, saltando a `26` .... Y en el tercer grupo hay un valor `112`

Comment: @A.Cedano aaaahhhh, no lo había visto... ya me preguntaba por qué nadie respondía esto!!! jajajaja ... De todas formas, el autor escribió "*Necesito que cuando i sea 1 entre en el primer caso, 2 en el segundo y 3 en el tercero y así sucesivamente*"  ... Me suena a que fue un error al escribir la condición

Comment: Esperamos que OP confirme eso. Si es una secuencia fija de 3 tu respuesta es genial, aunque faltaría quizá ponerle un límite (hasta que valor máximo iría la secuencia). ¿?

Comment: Validar que `k == 10` primero... Lo del límite máximo creo que ya lo establece en la condición del for... La verdad es que ahí no sé qué quiere el autor, me parece que queda fuera de lo que está preguntando: una forma de alternar entre 3 condiciones (por eso además no incluí el resto del código, sólo lo relevante)

Comment: Tienes razón, el límite estaría sin duda en la condición del bucle. Luego, casi seguro que lo de la secuencia es un error al redactar la pregunta, no tiene mucho sentido que a partir de un número los grupos se intercambien y donde está el `112` supongo que iría un `12`

Comment: Hola, en lo del 26 me he colado. Debería ir el 25. Creo que con restos no funcionaría, imaginándonos el caso del 6 el resto dividiéndolo entre 1, 2 o 3 sería, en los tres casos, 0. Ah y lo del límite sí está establecido en la condición del bucle.

Comment: Es el resto de dividirlo **por 3**, que da `0` y por eso entra en el `else` (la 3ra opción)... O sea, sí, funciona... para la suma directa en `k`, `k += ((6 - 1) % 3) * 3` --> `k += (5 % 3) * 3` --> `k += (2) * 3` --> `k += 6` --> `k == 16` ... también funciona

Comment: Lo del error de la pregunta, deberías editar la pregunta para aclararlo... las otras respuestas que recibiste están respondiendo al caso con ese error

Comment: Perdona, tenías razón. Me he liado yo con los restos. Funciona perfectamente, muchas gracias a ambos.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear tres arrays de números con los valores a comparar en cada caso y usar [la interfaz `IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) (Java 8+), para comprobar si `i` está en esa lista.

Aquí un ejemplo sencillo:

```
    int[] mAlpha = new int[]{1,4,7};  /*Completar con los otros valores*/
    int[] mBeta  = new int[]{2,5,8};  /*Completar con los otros valores*/
    int[] mGamma = new int[]{3,6,9};  /*Completar con los otros valores*/

    if ( k == 10 && IntStream.of(mAlpha).anyMatch(x -> x == i) ) {
        // k=10; esta asignación sobra
    } else if ( k == 10 && IntStream.of(mBeta).anyMatch(x -> x == i) ) {
        k=13;
    } else if (k == 10 && IntStream.of(mGamma).anyMatch(x -> x == i) ) {
        k=16;
    }
```

Si tu versión de Java es inferior a la 8 puedes igual crear un `List` de `Integer` y comparar usando `contains`, cabe decir que en este caso [ocurriría un Autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) y que el código sería menos óptimo. Si usas Java 8 deberías por tanto optar por `IntStream`.

Comment: Se podría hacer. Pero esa no es la idea exacta a la que me refiero. Me gustaría que, el que se cumplan las condiciones, dependiera del valor límite (el máximo valor que alcanza i). Me explico, que de forma "automática" si cambio la condición del for que establece el valor máximo, funcionara igualmente. Si un día necesito que i pueda alcanzar el valor 1000 (por ejemplo), tendría que meter demasiados números en las listas.

Comment: @ trikimg en ese caso lo suyo es crear tu propia fórmula, la cual exprese la lógica que acabas de explicar. Es lo que ha indicado @pollo en su excelente respuesta. Lo sugerido e mi respuesta ha sido por los cambios en la secuencia de números y pensando que solo se quería comparar esos valores fijos. Pero si se sigue una secuencia lógica lo más simple y práctico es recurrir a las matemáticas, que para eso existen :).